# Custom recall metric giving wrong results and not updating - tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I want to implement some simple custom metrics in tensorflow.
As a first step, I am trying to implement the usual recall by closely following the `CategoricalTruePositives` example in https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate. The main difference is in the `result()` method.

The code runs fine, but the logged metric presents a serious issue: it has the (wrong) value of `1.0` throughout the whole training.

Below is my code.

(*Note*: Although I am not using the true negatives and false positives, they are not there by mistake: I intend to use them later on.)

```py
class CategoricalRecall(Metric):
    def __init__(self, name="categorical_recall", **kwargs):
        super(CategoricalRecall, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.true_positives = self.add_weight(name="ctp", initializer="zeros")
        self.true_negatives = self.add_weight(name="ctn", initializer="zeros")
        self.false_positives = self.add_weight(name="cfp", initializer="zeros")
        self.false_negatives = self.add_weight(name="cfn", initializer="zeros")

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.bool)
        y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, tf.bool)

        # true positives
        values = tf.logical_and(tf.equal(y_true, True), tf.equal(y_pred, True))
        values = tf.cast(values, "float32")
        self.true_positives.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(values))

        # true negatives
        values = tf.logical_and(tf.equal(y_true, False), tf.equal(y_pred, False))
        values = tf.cast(values, "float32")
        self.true_negatives.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(values))

        # false positives
        values = tf.logical_and(tf.equal(y_true, False), tf.equal(y_pred, True))
        values = tf.cast(values, "float32")
        self.false_positives.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(values))

        # false negatives
        values = tf.logical_and(tf.equal(y_true, True), tf.equal(y_pred, False))
        values = tf.cast(values, "float32")
        self.false_negatives.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(values))

    def result(self):
        return tf.math.truediv(self.true_positives, (self.true_positives + self.false_negatives))

    def reset_states(self):
        # The state of the metric will be reset at the start of each epoch.
        self.true_positives.assign(0.0) 
        self.true_negatives.assign(0.0) 
        self.false_positives.assign(0.0)
        self.false_negatives.assign(0.0)
```

Any help is appreciated.